# Delete Users from SQL database with a email like

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to delete a massive amount of users who have the email address from the domain: "shopchristianpump"

I have a wordpress site and in the MySQL database trying to just list them all first:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_email` like 'shopchristianpump'
```

I know there are users in there with this domain however it returns zero results.

i.e 5r8c32cYon at shopchristianpump and 677digqZ at shopchristianpump

Can you help with what the delete statement would be to remove all users from here

Cheers

Comment: % <-- you're missing some of these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE user_email like '%@shopchristianpump%';
```

Comment: If you delete users using this approach I'd suggest to check the wp_usermeta table and eventually other tables used in WP, otherwise you might leave orphan data there. This gist can be helpful: https://gist.github.com/carlosleopoldo/5897807

Answer (score 3):

Use wildcard operator (`%`). Wildcard means, that the content of the symbol's place could be anything.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_email` LIKE '%@shopchristianpump.com';
```

If shopchristianpump's domain name is different that .com, then replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following statement to view them first, this is a contains search, it will find all the emails of the domain name, regardless of the top level domain(.com, .netm .org)

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_email` like '%@shopchristianpump%';
```

If everything seems ok, then delete them with

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_email` LIKE '%@shopchristianpump%';
```

More info of SQL Wildcards here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp